# Er Diagram from a dict Python

Tags: python, dictionary, visualization, erd

I have a database. The task was to get all the views, see what is inside and visualize all the tables and views that are inside. I made a dict like:

```
{
    view_name1: [tab1, tab2, view_name2],
    view_name2: [tab4, tab99, view_name43],
    ...
}
```

So as u can see, there might be the same views or tabs in each view.

But now I gotta create a ER diagram with all relations. I found ERALCHEMY but it works only from databases or SQLALCHEMY models.

**So how to create a er diagram from a dict or maybe from a DataFrame. Or I should create a model from a dict?**

Comment: You could probably use Graphviz for rendering the final chart, and the Python Graphviz library https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/ to make it easier to generate the file that Graphviz renders.